# is eating 6 times instead of 3 times will help reduce belly fat?

Tags: bellyfat

some suggest cut 3 times food and eat same amount 6 times....

still total calorie that body take is same right ?

than how its going to reduce belly fat ?

or skipping morning breakfast will help us to reduce belly fat ? than we will face gastric Problems right ?

Comment: can some one please explain why this question is `off topic` ?